# Check if a value is in the list with Linq c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List `public static List<string> HandledErrorCodes { get; } = new List<string> {...` with some data inside. And i need to check, if a value (*ex.ErrorCode*) is inside this list. I thing the best way is with Linq:

```
if ((exception is DomainException ex 
    && CommandTriggerCommon.HandledErrorCodes.Any(ex.ErrorCode))
```

But i'm getting an error "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func<string, bool>'". What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [List.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0) to find if an element exists, not `Any`:

```
if ((exception is DomainException ex 
    && CommandTriggerCommon.HandledErrorCodes.Contains(ex.ErrorCode))
```

If you insist on using LINQ (why?) you need to specify the condition as a `Func<T,bool>`

```
if ((exception is DomainException ex 
    && CommandTriggerCommon.HandledErrorCodes.Any(e=>e==ex.ErrorCode))
```

Both methods will iterate over the entire list to find matches. If you have more than a few dozen error codes you can speed this up by using a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) instead of a `List<string>`. `HashSet.Contains` will be far faster than a linear search as the number of items grows.

Comment: Good shout with `Contains`. No need to use LINQ here at all.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

`Any` takes `Func<T,bool>` (or in your specific case `Func<string,bool>`) - you're passing it just a `string`

It should be `... && CommandTriggerCommon.HandledErrorCodes.Any(ec => ec == ex.ErrorCode)`